# Oculus Virtual Desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors, oculus-rift

I would like to use Oculus Virtual Desktop with my work laptop so I could use Oculus to have several monitors when working remotely.

However, my company laptop only allows to install a restricted list of software, not including anything related to Oculus or Virtual Desktop.

Is there any workaround to this? Maybe installing Oculus Virtual Desktop in a 2nd device and connect it with an HDMI to my work laptop?